# Simple modules over a matrix ring and their the dimension of their tensor product over the base field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, semi-simple-rings

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $k$ be a field, and let $R=M_{n}(k)$, the non-commutative ring of
> $n \times n$ matrices over $k$.
>
> (a) Give examples of a simple left $R$-module $M$ and of a simple
> right $R$-module N.
>
> (b) Can you find another simple left $R$-module $M^{\prime}$ which is
> not isomorphic to $M ?$ (Either find one or explain why there is none
> such.)
>
> (c) Compute $\operatorname{dim}_{k}\left(N \otimes_{R} M\right)$.

For (a), I know that any simple $R$-module is isomorphic to $k^n$ with the standard action of $R$ on $k^n$ and this gives (b). A reference can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782690/simple-module-over-matrix-rings). A down-to-earth reasoning on why this is true is to note that any simple $R$-module is at least cyclic so that $M=Rv$ for some $v\in M$. Then I can identify $v$ with a vector in $k^n$ and the action of $R$ on $v$ as the action of a matrix on the vector in $k^n$ via left multiplication. I think this makes some sense at least...

Going back to (a), the idea I have is to specify the action on the left and right on some vector of $k^n$. So for instance, I take $M=Re_1$ where $e_1$ is the standard basis vector in $k^n$.

However, I am stuck on how to approach (c). So the tldr of what I would like is this:

1. Can I have some hints on (c)?
2. Does there exist a straightforward proof that the only simple modules are $k^n$ that does not use Morita equivalence?
3. Does my "idea" for giving a simple left $R$-module $M$ and a simple right $R$-module $N$ work?